OpenVPN Disconnect TLS Handshake failed
I have openvpn tunnels between two servers and a large number of clients who are 4G modems in a large area.
TLS and openvpn version :
OpenVPN 2.3.18 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6]
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018, LZO 2.09
Openvpn works with UDP port 11000
A few times a month I have random disconnections on several of my stations (100 modems disconnected out of 2000 for the last occurrence) in different regions. Once disconnected, clients try to reach server A or server B without success for 45 minutes approximately.
Here are the logs I was able to find on the client side:
2024-07-17 19:17:59 openvpn[14373]: [Worldline Server] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
2024-07-17 19:17:59 openvpn[14373]: /sbin/ifconfig tun0 0.0.0.0
2024-07-17 19:17:59 openvpn[14373]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
2024-07-17 19:18:09 openvpn[14373]: Control Channel Authentication: using '/var/openvpn/secret1.pem' as a OpenVPN static key file
2024-07-17 19:18:09 openvpn[14373]: UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
2024-07-17 19:18:09 openvpn[14373]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:11000
Here are the logs for servers A and B in loop :
Wed Jul 17 09:17:57 2024 X.X.X.X:2552 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed Jul 17 09:17:57 2024 X.X.X.X:2552 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Wed Jul 17 09:17:57 2024 X.X.X.X:2552 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Usually after several attempts, about 45min, the tunnel authentication works and the tunnel goes back up.

The "TLS Error" part of the log can sometimes be a red herring, but if you keep reading, it says "check network connectivity". This is the error you get any time the connection cannot be made, meaning your internet service might be down, local network might be down, and so on. Firewalls can also cause this but the intermittent nature suggests simple network outages.

All stations are on the same network and not all disconnect in the same zone. HTTP traffic, for example, works fine when the VPN tunnel is down.
